# Strapi Authentication Issue for getting JWT Token

Tags: strapi

{
"identifier" : "hitman@gmail.com",
"password" : "test123"
}

http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local

"error": {
"status": 403,
"name": "ForbiddenError",
"message": "Forbidden",
"details": {}
}

Answer (score 0):

Hiho!

In order to let anyone access the api for auth strapi users permissions plugin comes with all permissions uncheck, you will have to go to roles permissions and for each setup the endpoints you want to give access for the selected role. To do that ,

make sure you go to Strapi admin dashboard and you go to:

Settings -> Users & Permissions plugin -> Roles

[image]

Select Public then scroll down to Permissions -> Users-permissions

[image]

At Auth make sure you have check "connect", save and the public (guests) will be able to connect via API